# CPU constantly at 100%, but in Process Explorer usage is around 5%

Tags: windows-10, cpu, task-manager, process-explorer

Task Manager shows CPU usage constantly at 100%, but Process Explorer shows CPU usage at about 5%. I've tried the solution presented in [CPU Constantly at 100% In Task Manager, But Not in Process Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/1060567/cpu-constantly-at-100-in-task-manager-but-not-in-process-explorer), but it did not work for me. When I reboot the PC into Safe Mode, though, everything is OK.

How can I resolve the discrepancy?

Comment: What about Task Manager’s Detail view? Does it (roughly) add up to 100% usage? You might want to sort by CPU usage to check it.

Comment: I think it does, however the usage change very dynamicaly.
For example: dwm.exe (44%), taskmgr.exe (30%), csrss.exe (10%), chrome.exe (10%) and system interruptions (6%) and in the next second taskmgr.exe (or other process) jumps to 80% and other processes are in lower usage.

Comment: use [WPRUI/WPA](https://superuser.com/a/1164299/174557) to analyze the cpu usage of the proceseses. for 3rd party tools like chrome, add the debug symbols from the 3rd party tools ([chrome debug symbol server](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-windows))

Comment: I couldn't find anything helpful, except constant CPU usage by System Idle Process ( https://imgur.com/a/uudgO ). I look up properties of this process in Process Explorer and threads tab shows: ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x2160 on every core

Comment: the WPA shows that the cpu is 94% idle, this is fine. so active cpu usage is 6%.

Answer (score 0):

Try chasing the guilty process(es) in the Resource Monitor (type "resmon" in the Start Menu).

I had the same problem and the faulty app what not visible in the Task Manager, even in Administrator mode, no idea why.