# Windows 10 CPU Usage at 99%. Processes not showing correct CPU usage

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance, cpu-usage

On a Windows 10 16299.192 desktop system task manager always shows 99% usage. If I try killing the highest usage program all others suddenly show their CPU usage increasing to fill the gap, as if the CPU usage is being calculated as % of CPU cycles currently used instead of % CPU cycles available like normal.

I tried editing a registry key to allow me to disable the processor idle state (as has worked in the past) but no change even after a reboot.

Process Explorer does show the correct CPU usage numbers, with System Idle Process filling in the remainder of (100% - Current Usage) like normal.

Intel i3-4170 CPU. Let me know if there's any more information you might need.

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager]

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager and Process Explorer]

Answer (score 1):

Found this link after more digging with PowerCfg commands that finally did the trick.
[CPU Constantly at 100% In Task Manager, But Not in Process Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/1060567/cpu-constantly-at-100-in-task-manager-but-not-in-process-explorer#1061436)