# Task Manager does not show correct per-process CPU usage on Windows 10 1809

Tags: windows-10, cpu, process, cpu-usage

Under Windows 10 Pro for Workstations (Build 17763.55) Task Manager does not show correct CPU usage on a per-process basis. Processes that use up the entirety of the processor are reported to only use 2%, which is far from accurate. I originally noticed this while installing the operating system itself, as no process would ever climb above 2% despite clearly pushing my machine to it's limits. Any ideas?

This is Prime95 pushing the CPU to the maximum as seen under the "Details" tab...
[image: Prime95 process when seen under the "Details" tab]

... and this is Prime95 pushing the CPU to the maximum as seen under the "Processes" tab.
[image: Prime95 process when seen under the "Processes" tab]

This is a fresh upgrade from Windows 7 Ultimate, and I do not wish to redo a clean install at this time, as the point of upgrading was to keep my settings as they were.

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1291157/windows-10-cpu-usage-at-99-processes-not-showing-correct-cpu-usage) since the issue here isn't related to the fact that the CPU reports 100% usage, but is related to the fact that processes do not report correct usage on an individual basis. The CPU is not constantly shown to be at 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a known bug:
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/task-manager-shows-incorrect-cpu-usage-in-windows-10-october-2018-update/

> Microsoft acknowledged the bug in Task Manager last month when it released the RTM Build 17763 to the Windows Insiders in the Fast and Slow Ring. Unfortunately, the known issue also exists in the public version of Windows 10 October 2018 Update as the Task Manager is reporting inaccurate CPU usage.

Comment: Apparently this issue is only fixed in the Insider Builds as of yet. Thanks, Microsoft.